# AngularJS data binding not working

Tags: angularjs, bind

I wrote some simplified code on http://jsfiddle.net/gsche/1/

When I click the "Refresh" link, the "customer.name" model doesn't update the view.

I wrote the code on my local computer and debugged it with Batarang in Chrome.

The console doesn't show any errors. The Model page in Batarang shows the customer name changing on the right, associated with an old scope id, but the id's of the $scopes also change.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <p> <a href="#" ng-click="Refresh()">Refresh</a> </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name">
        </p>
        <p>{{ customer.name }}</p>
    </div>
</div>


function MainCtrl($scope) {


    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'TTT',
        id: 0
    };

    $scope.Refresh = function ($scope) {
        $scope.customer.name = 'Test';

    };

}
```

**Update 1 08.08.2013**
Thank you all (@EpokK, @Stewie, @Hippocrates). I undestand now the problem with jsfiddle, and the example works as it should.

However, in my test application, the {{customer.name}} binding works, but the "Refresh" click still doesn't change the {{customer.name}} in the view.

Here is the content of my application. I think it is the same as the jsfiddle example:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
  <body ng-app="roaMobileNgApp">


    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/angular-ui.css">

    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('roaMobileNgApp', ['ui'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('roaMobileNgApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.customer = {name: '',
                      id: 0};



    $scope.getDetails = function() {
        $scope.customer.name = 'Test';
    };

  });
```

**main.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <a href="#" ng-click="getDetails()">Refresh</a>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="customer.name"> {{ customer.name }} </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select "No wrap - in " in fiddle options (because otherwise your demo won't work), and remove the `$scope` parameter from your `Refresh` function. You don't need to pass in `$scope` because the function itself is defined inside the $scope.

```js
$scope.getDetails = function(){
  $scope.customer.name = 'Test';
};
```

Comment: Thank you all. The jsfiddle problem is solved, but the "Refresh" link in my application still doesn't update the "customer.name".

I updated my question with the source files.

Comment: I've got the answer to my problem. The a href="#" was causing a page refresh.

If anyone has the same problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127523/ng-click-does-not-update-model

Comment: It's valid HTML5 to not require an HREF in an anchor element so you can remove it.

Comment: @Stewie can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4

Answer (score 3):

Check my solution, I have edit your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gsche/10/

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'TTT',
        id: 0
    };

    $scope.getDetails = function () {
        $scope.customer.name = 'Test';
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way you loaded your scripts.

I like to load angular followed by my app.js containing controllers right at the end of the body:

```
...
    <script src="/assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

To get your fiddle working, all I did was change it from "onReady" to "in body" (It's the little dropdown near the top left.)

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/gsche/3/

onReady means your controller definition was wrapped in an onReady function by jsfiddle. By the time angular loaded and got to work, your controller was still undefined and angular had to go ahead and spit out the raw template.